# pyqt5: return QObject from slot

Tags: pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I'm trying to expose a method to QML in pyqt 5, and I need it to return a custom QObject. I can't seem to work out anyway to do this. The snippet below shows roughly what I'm trying to do. I've tried changed the result parameter to QObject, "QObject", and various other types. Each either gives me a different error message, or if no error, the QML receives null instead of the object. I've also tried registering Bar as a type, but still no help.

What is the right way to return a custom object like this? (Note: we've had this working in C++ previously.)

```
class Bar(QObject):
    # etc.

bar = Bar()

class Foo(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot(int, result=QObject)
    def foo(self, arg1):
        return bar
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot(int, result=QObject)
    def foo(self, arg1):
        sip.transferto(bar, bar)
        return bar
```

Comment: Where is sip coming from? Without any explanation, this does not help.